# date/time setting does not work after unplugging power adapter or sudden power cut in linux

Tags: linux, sync, time, date-time

For some reason, I want to configure the date/time in my Linux (CentOS 6.5) to be different from the **REAL** date/time, but the setting won't work if I turn my computer(desktop not laptop if this matters, **AND** this computer has no access to the Internet) on after a sudden power cut, the date/time will be the old date/time before the configuration, I unplug the power adapter manually to simulate the sudden power cut situation.

How to make the configuration still work after turning on the computer even a sudden power cut happens?

I **ONLY** care about the date/time setting problem here, no worries about the data loss or something like this after sudden power cut, so besides the UPS solution, are there other better solution? If I can just make some configuration inside the Linux, that would be the answer I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `hwclock -w` or `hwclock --systohc` right after changing your system time if you want it applied to the hardware clock immediately.